# How to display an image from Firebase in a tableView using Resizable cells?

Tags: swift, image, uitableview

I have a tableView that grabs information from Firebase. The content grabbed is text and photos. I followed this tutorial :https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells I followed the section called show me the art. For the Image view I used Aspect Fit. The text loads first and then the picture, but the image shows up in the wrong place, as in it's not in view and I have to scroll a long ways. I've tried playing with the estimated cell height, but it hasn't seemed to help. So TLDR: I'm using a custom tableView cell with an imageView and a label both of which are populated by data from Firebase. The cells are autoResizing. image of text before image has loaded: [image: Image of Cell before Image Loads] Here is the result after the image has loaded: [image: This is after the image has loaded. The image is nowhere in site and the text has been pushed down.]

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath) as! BooksTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

    let bookSnapShot: FIRDataSnapshot! = self.SecondResultArray[indexPath.row]

    let book = bookSnapShot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>

    let Author = book["Author"] as String!
    let Comment = book["Comment"] as String!
    let Genre = book["Genre"] as String!
    let User = book["User"] as String!
    let title = book["title"] as String!
    let bookPhoto = book["bookPhoto"] as String!
    let userID = book["userID"] as String!
    let userLocation = book["userLocation"] as String!
    let bookRate = book["bookRating"] as String!
    let userToBePushed = book["pushingID"] as String!
    let bookLat = book["bookLat"] as String!
    let bookLng = book["bookLng"] as String!

    if bookRate == "Age Restricted"{


        cell.bookLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.bookLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping



        cell.bookLabel?.text = "This book is age restricted that is why you are seeing a default image"
  + "\n" + "Title: " + title! as String + "\n" + "Author: " + Author! as String + "\n" + "Comment: " + Comment! as String + "\n" + "Genre: " + Genre! as String + "\n" + "User: " + User! as String + "\n" + "Location: " + userLocation! as String



    cell.bookImageView?.image = UIImage(named: "old-books-436498_640.jpg")?.circleMask


    }
    else {

    let url = URL(string: bookPhoto!)



    DispatchQueue.global(priority: DispatchQueue.GlobalQueuePriority.default).async {


        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

            let images = UIImage(data: data!)


            cell.bookImageView!.image = UIImage(data: data!)


            self.tableView.reloadData()
        });
    }




    cell.bookLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping

  cell.bookLabel?.text = "Title: " + title! as String + "\n" + "Author:    " + Author! as String + "\n" + "Comment: " + Comment! as String + "\n" + "Genre: " + Genre! as String + "\n" + "User: " + User! as String + "\n" + "\n" + "Location: " + userLocation! as String





    }

    cell.backgroundColor = .clear

   cell.bookLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white

    cell.bookLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Chalkduster", size: 20)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: can you show a screenshot of the problem ?

Comment: Yes I added them.

Comment: i just dont understand what is the problem ? the image shows and not the text ?

Comment: The text loads from firebase before the image does and then when the image loads the text is pushed down and the picture is not in view. The image of the book is an asset not the image from Firebase.

Comment: this might be a problem from your constraints,  i dont know what did you put as constraints. And try to use an async image loader library like SDWebImage

Comment: So you are saying that I should play around with the view Constraints? I am already loading the image async but maybe that library will do a better job.

Comment: Yes it might be a constraints problem.

Comment: yup, just had to play with the view constraints.